# "this" becomes undefined in ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, variables, angular-promise

"this" becomes undefined in ngOnInit

I am trying to push the object that is returned on a callback into a globally defined array.

but it gives error that

"cannot read property of undefined"

```
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {
items: Item[];
devices: any[];
constructor(private itemService: ItemService) {
    this.devices = new Array();
}
ngOnInit(): void {
    bluetooth.isBluetoothEnabled().then(
        enabled => console.log("Enabled ? " + enabled)
    );
    bluetooth.startScanning({
        serviceUUIDs: [],
        seconds: 4,
        onDiscovered: function(peripheral) {
            this.devices.push(peripheral);
        }
    }).then(function() {
        console.log("scanning complete");
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("error while scanning: " + err);
    });
    this.items = this.itemService.getItems();
}}
```

i get this error at

```
this.devices.push(peripheral);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `Arrow Function` to get hold on correct `this` inside function.

```
onDiscovered: function(peripheral)
```

should be

```
onDiscovered:(peripheral) => {

}
```

Comment: this seems to be correct but if i use

      this.devices.forEach(element => {
             console.log(element.UUID);
        });

in "then" , it gives the same error

Comment: further more i am expecting this.devices to be available for the UI so that i can bind it to some element.

Comment: @RaasMasood Then make every single function where you expect to get lexical `this` an arrow. This is what arrows are for.

Comment: AWSOME.!! got it. Thankyou !!

Comment: @estus Yes, God forbid you save off the `this` context into a variable to remove ambiguity.